# WordPress admin-post.php cannot handle form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `admin_post_{$action}` to handle the form. I just copy-paste the example from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/.

I created `front-page.php` in the theme directory and just paste in:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="our_action_hook">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then this in the `functions.php` :

```
add_action( 'admin_post_our_action_hook', 'am_our_action_hook_function' );
function am_our_action_hook_function() {
    // do something
}
```

But I got an error in the console: `400 bad request` . If I make this as a plugin, it works. But if I do it in a theme, it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 shows your request is not valid from your side.

you can check the console-> network and you can find the your request.

anyway, replace the form action with this:

```php
<form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="our_action_hook">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually already tried `admin_url( 'admin-post.php' )` , and it's also not working.

Comment: Can you show me the request header? @vwihw5xgpl